# PHP PDO fetch data from Array

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

> This Code Works Perfectly For Mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mem_tree' ";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:".mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
  $data[] = $row;
}
$itemsByReference = array();
```

> but When i'm trying to do with PDO it Doesn't Work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'mem_tree' ";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
   $data[] = $row;
}
$itemsByReference = array();
```

Comment: what error you see? please paste your error

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `$pdo = new PDO();` ? watch [THIS ref. Connection management](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). also, use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page so PHP will help handling errors

Comment: i'm using this code in js tree example, in the PDO code js tree is loading and loading, and in mysqli it works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here i found Solution of it

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mem_tree";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $final_arr = array();
  $data = array();
  $final_arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $data = $final_arr;
  $itemsByReference = array();
```